# How to get ID and Value of all Slide-Toggle elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I asked a question similar to this. But here my problem is a bit different. In a table column, I have Slide-Toggle elements, which users can make them true or false unlimited time. And after that there's a button user can submit all those true, false values. In my HTML those Slide-Toggle elements come from for loop which is generated from notifications array. What is the easiest and best way to get values(true, false) of all those slide-toggles with their IDs?As I mentioned I'll submit them that's why I want to do this. Here's what I tried below

**HTML**

```
<h3>Notifications</h3>
    <table class="table" id="thetable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Tasks</th>
                <th scope="col">IsFinished</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let not of notifications;" 
              [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': (not.isFinished ? '#dddddd' : 'white') }"
              >
                 <th scope="row">{{not.id+1}}</th>
                  <td>{{not.task}}</td>
                <td>
                        <section class="example-section">
                                <mat-slide-toggle
                                    [id]="not.id"
                                    class="example-margin"
                                    [color]="color"
                                    [checked]="not.isFinished"
                                    [disabled]="not.isFinished"
                                    (change)="onChange($event)"
                                    >
                                </mat-slide-toggle>
                              </section>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()">Add Task</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
            </div>
```

**TypeScirpt** (How Array comes here)

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.notifications=this.notificationService.getNotifications();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind toggle with `ngModel` something like

```
<mat-slide-toggle [id]="not.id" class="example-margin" [color]="color"
 [checked]="not.isFinished" [(ngModel)]="not.isFinished"[disabled]="not.isFinished" (change)="onChange($event)" >
 </mat-slide-toggle>
```

then in on save method

```
 onSave(){
      this.notifications.forEach((n)=>{
      console.log(n.id) //this is the id of your toggle
      console.log(n.isFinished)//this is the value of toggle
      })
    }
```

**UPDATE**

as per your comment you don't want to use `ngModel` in that case you can check if you toggle element contains `mat-checked` class as angular material add checked class if toggle is active so remove ngmodel and change your mathod to

```
 onSave(){
          this.notifications.forEach((n)=>{
          console.log(n.id) //this is the id of your toggle
           var ele=document.getElementById(n.id)
           console.log(ele.classList.contains('mat-checked'))//this is the value 
         of toggle
          })
        }
```

Comment: that works but ngModel binding make them disabled after true comes.Thats how my table works.For finished tasks user shouldn't be able to change their value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id of toggled id on change, pass `not` in `(change)="onChange(not)"`. This for your reference to keep track of id's changed where you can create a separate array for it

While saving:

```
onSave(){
  this.finishedNotifications = this.notifications.filter((n) => {
    return n.id && n.isFinished; // filters and returns notifications which are finished only
  })
}
```